# Is it right to call voxelization an approximation? What other descriptions are there?

Tags: terminology, machine-learning

Is it right to call voxelization an approximation? What other descriptions are there?

I've struggled with understanding the purpose of voxelization, because different sources seem to describe it differently. Some associate it with filtering, segmenting, ...

I want to call it *approximation* similar to how e.g. continuous functions are approximated using simple functions. So in this sense I would say:

> *Voxelization* is about approximating or giving an approximation to a more complex shape (e.g. a point cloud) that approximates its shape.

It's intuitive that the process also does filtering, because it discards information. It also does segmenting, because it creates "segmentation". Although since it loses information, then I'm not sure if *segmenting* is appropriate word.

Comment: Isn't it more specifically a discretization? Just as pixelization discretizes an analog 2D image by assigning black/white or grayscale to each little square, and represents it by a pixel. But yes, it does approximate continuous shapes on a discrete grid.

Comment: @Conifold That I would say is a "small semantic difference", since discretization is a form of approximation?

Comment: Up to you. When people in numerical analysis introduce approximation on a grid they usually say that they "discretized" the problem.